# How to change style in android webview by injecting javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, css, webview

When I inject `document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.background = "red";` in developers console in firefox, background becomes red. But when I do `webview.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByTagName(\"body\")[0].style.background = \"red\";");` in android webview, whole content in it gets replaced by the word "red". Why is background color not changing and content is being replaced? Also, how can I change the style properties in webview using javascript?

Comment: Have you been able to fix this? I have the same problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem by injecting the following instead:

```
webview.loadUrl("javascript:(function() {document.getElementsByTagName(\"body\")[0].style.background = \"red\";})()");
```

Comment: Thank you for providing the solution